# Can this loopy array process be sped up?

Tags: arrays, numpy

Consider two given arrays: (in this sample, these arrays are based on n=5)

**Given**: array **m** has shape (n, 2n).  When n = 5, each row of **m** holds a random arrangement of integers 0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4.

```
import numpy as np

m= np.array([[4, 2, 2, 3, 0, 1, 3, 1, 0, 4],
             [2, 4, 0, 4, 3, 2, 0, 1, 1, 3],
             [0, 2, 3, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 4, 0],
             [2, 1, 2, 4, 3, 0, 0, 4, 3, 1],
             [2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1]])
```

**Given**: array **t** has shape (n^2, 4).  When n = 5, the first two columns (m_row, val) hold all 25 permutations pairs of 0 to 4.
The 1st column refers to **rows of array m**.  The 2nd column refers to **values in array m**.
For now, the last two columns hold dummy value 99 that will be replaced.

```
t = np.array([[0, 0, 99, 99],
              [0, 1, 99, 99],
              [0, 2, 99, 99],
              [0, 3, 99, 99],
              [0, 4, 99, 99],
              [1, 0, 99, 99],             
              [1, 1, 99, 99],            
              [1, 2, 99, 99],
              [1, 3, 99, 99],
              [1, 4, 99, 99],
              [2, 0, 99, 99],
              [2, 1, 99, 99],
              [2, 2, 99, 99],
              [2, 3, 99, 99],
              [2, 4, 99, 99],
              [3, 0, 99, 99],
              [3, 1, 99, 99],
              [3, 2, 99, 99],
              [3, 3, 99, 99],
              [3, 4, 99, 99],
              [4, 0, 99, 99],
              [4, 1, 99, 99],
              [4, 2, 99, 99],
              [4, 3, 99, 99],
              [4, 4, 99, 99]])
```

**PROBLEM**: I want to replace the dummy values in the last two columns of **t**, as follows:
Let's consider **t** row [1, 3, 99, 99].  So from **m**'s row=1, I determine the indices of the two columns that hold **value 3**.  These are columns (4,9), so the **t** row is updated to [1, 3, 4, 9].
In the same way, **t** row [4, 2, 99, 99] becomes [4, 2, 0, 8].

I currently do this by **looping through each column i of array m**, looking for the two instances where m[m_row, i] = val, then updating array **t**.  (slow!)
**Is there a way to speed up this process, perhaps using vectorization or broadcasting?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
import itertools

# First 2 columns
t = np.array(list(itertools.product(range(m.shape[0]), repeat=2)))
# Add columns - indices of "wanted" elements
t = np.hstack((t, np.apply_along_axis(lambda row, arr:
    np.nonzero(arr[row[0]] == row[1])[0], 1, t, m)))
```

The result, for your data sample (*m* array), is:

```
array([[0, 0, 4, 8],
       [0, 1, 5, 7],
       [0, 2, 1, 2],
       [0, 3, 3, 6],
       [0, 4, 0, 9],
       [1, 0, 2, 6],
       [1, 1, 7, 8],
       [1, 2, 0, 5],
       [1, 3, 4, 9],
       [1, 4, 1, 3],
       [2, 0, 0, 9],
       [2, 1, 3, 7],
       [2, 2, 1, 6],
       [2, 3, 2, 4],
       [2, 4, 5, 8],
       [3, 0, 5, 6],
       [3, 1, 1, 9],
       [3, 2, 0, 2],
       [3, 3, 4, 8],
       [3, 4, 3, 7],
       [4, 0, 1, 3],
       [4, 1, 2, 9],
       [4, 2, 0, 8],
       [4, 3, 4, 7],
       [4, 4, 5, 6]], dtype=int64)
```

## Edit

The above code relies on the fact that each row in *m* contains
just 2 "wanted" values.

To make the code resistant to the case that some row contains either too many
or not enough "wanted" values (even none):

1. Define a function returning indices of "wanted" elements as:

   ```
   def inds(row, arr):
       ind = np.nonzero(arr[row[0]] == row[1])[0]
       return np.pad(ind, (0,2), constant_values=99)[0:2]
   ```
2. Change the second instruction to:

   ```
   t = np.hstack((t, np.apply_along_axis(inds, 1, t, m)))
   ```

To test this variant, change the first line of *m* to:

```
[4, 2, 2, 3, 5, 5, 3, 1, 5, 4]
```

i.e. it:

- does not contain *0* elements,
- contains only a single *1*.

Then the initial part of the result is:

```
array([[ 0,  0, 99, 99],
       [ 0,  1,  7, 99],
```

so that the missing indices in the result are filled with *99*.

Comment: Fast!  Your edit provides much increased functionality.